# Alamofire post request with body in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to make post request with alamofire with body, but I keep having this error code "Message: An error has occurred."
I run the same api in obj-c and afnetworking, all works fine. Am I using the wrong way to make parameters?

```
let parameters: [String: Any] = ["ID": "aaaa@test.com", "PW": "12345", "LoginType": "IDPW", "PushKey": "ios"]
Alamofire.request(loginApi, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print(response)
        }
```

Body i send using Objective-C & function

```
     NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                             @"LoginType": @"IDPW",
                             @"ID": @"aaaa@test.com",
                             @"PW": @"12345",
                             @"PushKey":  @"ios"
                             };
     - (void) AsyncHttpRequestWithMethod:(NSString * _Nonnull)method
                      URLString:(NSString * _Nonnull)URLString
                     parameters:(NSDictionary * _Nullable)parameters
                        headers:(NSDictionary * _Nullable)headers
                 uploadProgress:(nullable void (^)(NSProgress * _Nullable uploadProgress)) uploadProgressBlock
               downloadProgress:(nullable void (^)(NSProgress * _Nullable downloadProgress)) downloadProgressBlock
              completionHandler:(nullable void (^)(NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, id _Nullable responseObject,  NSError * _Nullable error))completionHandler {

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:method URLString:URLString parameters:parameters error:nil];

req.timeoutInterval = intTimeInterval;

if (headers && headers.count > 0) {
    NSArray *keys = headers.allKeys;
    for (int i = 0; i < headers.count; i ++) {
        [req addValue:headers[keys[i]] forHTTPHeaderField:keys[i]];
    }
}

[[manager dataTaskWithRequest:req uploadProgress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
    if (uploadProgressBlock) uploadProgressBlock(uploadProgress);
} downloadProgress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {
    if (downloadProgressBlock) downloadProgressBlock(downloadProgress);
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    NSLog(@"completionHandler......");

    completionHandler(response, responseObject, error);
}] resume];
```

}

Comment: What is the exact json body you send in Objective-C?

Comment: I think you are missing the "Content-Type" header. have you mentioned it anywhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a POST request with BODY in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982513/how-to-send-a-post-request-with-body-in-swift)

Comment: @Brandon I send nsdictionary in Objective-C. I've edit my question

Comment: @Shruti I add headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type":"application/json"] in my code still not working

Comment: but you need to pass headers in request also. after encoding header paramter should also come

Comment: @fritz here is working code https://stackoverflow.com/a/52312239/10150796 please check

Comment: parameter keys are different in Obj-C and swift codes (ID vs MemberID, PW vs MemberPW). if the request succeeds(200 status code) and you are still seeing error response from api, this might be the problem.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani I've tried ur code, still getting  Message = "An error has occurred.";

Comment: @fritz please share your request API URL so i can check it.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr That's what I thought. But i can't figure out how to make parameters working in swift

Comment: @fritz parameter variable look good to me, did you tried making them same as in Obj-C?

Comment: @fritz parameters are right one more thing make sure that is there any special key define from the server side to pass parameters on that key.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani I think sever is working, i use other obj-c project to run the api and parameters. It's working. Can I share my request API privately for u ? I'm new to this.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr Yes. I use same key and value like i use in obj-c.

Comment: @fritz i have already say to share this in my previous comment. and also update ypur obj-c api call code in question.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani I've edit my question.

Comment: i figure it out. Thanks guys!!!!

Comment: @fritz Your request parameters different in objective-c and swift code.

Comment: @fritz share your answer, it may help someone in future

Answer (score 1):

In your request `headers` is missing, Please use the following code to get the result.

```
let headers = ["Content-Type":"application/json"]    
let parameter = ["MemberID": "aaaa@test.com", "MemberPW": "12345", "LoginType": "IDPW", "PushKey": "ios"]

            Alamofire.request(loginApi, method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
                .responseJSON { (response) in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success:
                        print("success",response)
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print("failure",error)
                    }
            }
```

[image]

Comment: I add headers in the request and still getting 
SUCCESS: {
    Message = "An error has occurred.";
}

Comment: Okay you API call is getting response success block, but there is some issue may occur from API side.

Answer (score 0):

Your codes looks good to me.

Without more information it is difficult to identity that what is actual problem.

As per me possible problem is  `encoding`

change

`JSONEncoding.default`

with other available options like `URLEncoding.default`

Let me know if it is not working then I will delete my answer